Generating PDF Reports with Mathematical Expressions Using Python
I'm working on generating a report that includes numerous mathematical expressions such as matrices, vectors, and equations. I'm planning to use Python for this task. One of the most commonly used libraries is Report Lab, but it does not support LaTeX rendering. Some have suggested generating LaTeX equations as images and embedding them into the PDF. However, this approach does not provide good alignment and resolution of images, and it's not very flexible.
Can anyone suggest a better way to include high-quality LaTeX-rendered equations in my PDF report using Python? An example demonstrating this would be greatly appreciated.
Example:
Suppose I want to include the following matrix equation in my report:


How can I achieve this with good alignment and resolution?

I found that Pylatex, is sufficient to generate the reports, some features are not available, but you can achieve it using direct Latex format code.
You need Latex Compiler  , Here I'm using MikTex

